# Reversing order of columns in file

Tags: unix

Im working with database which looks very common:

```
age:position:name:
```

I still don't know why this database is made in this order, but for better orientation and manipulation, I would like to reverse the order like this:

```
name:age:position.
```

I'm trying to do it with unix like this:

```
datab=`cut -d : -f1,2,3 inf.major`
age=`echo "$datab" | cut -d : -f1 > age`
pos=`echo "$datab" | cut -d : -f2 > pos`
name=`echo "$datab" | cut -d : -f3 > name`
paste -d : "age" "pos" "name" > inf.major
```

This is quite laboriously. It would be ok if the data had only few "sections" divided by `:` but it has more than 10. Is there any way how to achieve the same result but dynamicly/faster?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`/`gawk`:

```
gawk -F":" '{print $3":"$2":"$1;}' inf.major
```

This will separate each line of your file at `:` and print the first three elements in reversed order.